# What is this Objective C code in swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I have found a solution to my problem, but the code is in Objective C. Please could someone tell me what this is in swift?

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can use this. It's pretty handy while converting objc to swift most of the time. https://objectivec2swift.com/#/converter/

Comment: You can use the site  http://swiftify.com/  to convert your objective c code to swift.

Comment: A good tip for Swift Developers: Learn of to read Objective-C (not how to write it). It's quite useful as you can see because a lot of issues have already been answered in Objective-C (and since it uses the common Cocoa/CocoaTouch) you'll save time. Then you can check the documentation for theses objects and how to translate them into Swift.

Answer (score 6):

**Try this :**

```
do {
       try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
       try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
       UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()

   }catch{
        print("error")
   }
```

And further, if you need to convert any code from **Objective C** to **Swift** you can convert by using the following Link.

https://objectivec2swift.com

Comment: You forget to add the third line code in the question. And +1 for handling the errors.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
do{ 
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
}catch {
   print("error")
}
```

Also, you can do it from XCode.

1. Select the ObjC code that you want to convert.
2. Go `Editor > Swiftify > Convert Selection to Swift`
3. Done

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full conversion of the code :

```
do {
  try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
  try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
  UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
} catch {
  //handle error
  print(error)
}
```

The best way to convert the objective-c code would be to check out the latest documentation. Go to Xcode > Window > Developer Documentation, and then search for the class (e.g. AVAudioSession in this case)